# Find count in WindowedStream - Flink

Tags: scala, stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am pretty new in the world of Streams and I am facing some issues in my first try.

More specifically, I am trying to implement a count and groupBy functionality in a sliding window using Flink.

I 've done it in a normal `DateStream` but I am not able to make it work in a `WindowedStream`.

Do you have any suggestion on how can I do it?

```
val parsedStream: DataStream[(String, Response)] = stream
      .mapWith(_.decodeOption[Response])
      .filter(_.isDefined)
      .map { record =>
        (
          s"${record.get.group.group_country}, ${record.get.group.group_state}, ${record.get.group.group_city}",
          record.get
        )
      }

val result: DataStream[((String, Response), Int)] = parsedStream
      .map((_, 1))
      .keyBy(_._1._1)
      .sum(1)

// The output of result is 
// ((us, GA, Atlanta,Response()), 14)
// ((us, SA, Atlanta,Response()), 4)

result
      .keyBy(_._1._1)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))

//the following part doesn't compile

      .apply(
        new WindowFunction[(String, Int), (String, Int), String, TimeWindow] {
          def apply(
                   key: Tuple,
                   window: TimeWindow,
                   values: Iterable[(String, Response)],
                   out: Collector[(String, Int)]
                   ) {}
        }
      )
```

Compilation Error:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  [R](function: (String, org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow, Iterable[((String, com.flink.Response), Int)], org.apache.flink.util.Collector[R]) => Unit)(implicit evidence$28: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R] <and>
  [R](function: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction[((String, com.flink.Response), Int),R,String,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow])(implicit evidence$27: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction[((String, com.flink.Response), Int),(String, com.flink.Response),String,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow]{def apply(key: String,window: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow,input: Iterable[((String, com.flink.Response), Int)],out: org.apache.flink.util.Collector[(String, com.flink.Response)]): Unit})
      .apply(
```

Comment: Hey, can You paste the compile error that You are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Your code and found the errors, it seems that you have an error when declaring the types for your `WindowFunction`.

The documentation says that the expected types for `WindowFunction` are `WindowFunction[IN, OUT, KEY, W <: Window]`. Now, if you take a look at Your code, Your `IN` is the type of the datastream that You are calculating windows on. The type of the stream is `((String, Response), Int)` and not as declared in the code `(String, Int)`.

If You will change the part that is not compiling to :

```
.apply(new WindowFunction[((String, Response), Int), (String, Response), String, TimeWindow] {
        override def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[((String, Response), Int)], out: Collector[(String, Response)]): Unit = ???
})
```

EDIT: As for the second example the error occurs because of the same reason in general. When You are using `keyBy` with `Tuple` You have two possible functions to use `keyBy(fields: Int*)`, which uses integer to access field of the tuple using index provided (this is what You have used). And also `keyBy(fun: T => K)` where You provide a function to extract the key that will be used.

But there is one important difference between those functions one of them returns key as `JavaTuple` and the other one returns the key with its exact type. 
So basically If You change the `String` to `Tuple` in Your simplified example it should compile clearly.

Comment: I got a compile error again. 
I updated my question.

Comment: Seems that the error is related with `AccumulatingProcessingTimeWindowOperator` which does not exist in the latest Flink.

Comment: The code below is compiled but doesn't do the correct thing
```.apply(
        (key: String, twindow: TimeWindow, it: Iterable[((String, Response), Int)], coll: Collector[(String, Int, Date)]) => {
          print(key)
          coll.collect((key, it.size, new Date(twindow.getEnd)))
        })```

Comment: Can You please elaborate what is wrong with the given solution ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler example that we can work on

```
val source: DataStream[(JsonField, Int)] = env.fromElements(("hello", 1), ("hello", 2))

    val window2 = source
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1))
      .apply(new WindowFunction[(JsonField, Int), Int, String, TimeWindow] {})
```

Comment: Hey, I have made an edit to my answer that explains why this example does not work.