# Apache Flink - Windowing - AggregateFunction for count

Tags: apache-flink

My purpose is obtain the count of elements per window.

I was expecting to see a count method on the windowed stream (like sum,min and max). But this seems to be missing.

I think this can be simply implemented by using ProcessWindowFunction (by getting the size of the iterable) or by using a custom AggregateFunction (this is a little bit more complex)?

I have the impression that AggregateFunction must be preferred over ProcessWindowFunction because of smaller state size. Is this correct?

So my question: If there is no predefined count method for count aggregation how should I implement it? If AggregateFunction is the way to go could you please suggest an implementation

Regards

Comment: See if the following helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942080/find-count-in-windowedstream-flink